# Can you link an external XSD in your XML schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

So say I have have mytype.xsd

```
  <!--SIMPLETYPE DEFINITIONS-->
  <xs:simpleType name="datetime">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{8}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

and myelement.xsd

```
  <xs:element name="StartTime" type="datetime"/>
  <xs:element name="EndTime" type="datetime" />
```

Is there something like `<xs:schema href="mytype.xsd` which I can use to link myelement.xsd with mytype.xsd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are two flavors of re-use. You can either

```
<include schemaLocation="..."/>
```

or

```
<import namespace="..." schemaLocation=".../>
```

another schema.

Which one to choose is another matter. Inclusion is more like inheritance while importation is more akin to composition, if you are accustomed to those concepts. In my experience, <import> is quite natural and the more widely used mechanism.

Comment: Which one to choose is governed entirely by the target namespace of the schemas involved.  Inclusion brings other components in the same target namespace into the schema; import brings components from a different namespace into the schema.  It is not a matter of taste and has nothing to do with inheritance, composition, naturalness, or artificiality.

Comment: OK, but if you start from scratch, there's always an element of choice involved. The structuring of your components doesn't happen automatically. Of course it is a matter of taste.